# WPF dynamic property binding with XElement not work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, linq-to-xml

I think I found a bug in WPF or I don't know something about dynamic properties and binding.

In a code bellow I want to add (when editing) a node to XDocument if not exists. To do this I create attached property which monitor text changed event on TextBox and if user type something in TextBox I check if element exists in XDocument, if not then add it.

(For explain `p1` and `p2` are XElement objects.)

Everything work OK if I use only `p1`. When I type first character event fire check node not exists and add it to XDocument (typed character disappear but that is not important) when I type next characters node is correct updating.

Now if I use `p2` and type character in TextBox then node is creating (character is NOT disappear) and when I type next characters, node is not updating. That not work properly.

What I observe is that when in xaml I reorder `Row 1` and `Row 2` that `Row 2` is above `Row 1`

```
<!--ROW P2-->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="p2:" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Element[p2].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        local:TextChangedAction.AddNodeIfNotExists="p2" />
<!--ROW P1-->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="p1:" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Element[p1].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        local:TextChangedAction.AddNodeIfNotExists="p1" />
```

then works `p2` and not work `p1`. It's looks like only first element in collection properly update binding.

Furthermore if I edit (in not reordered version) `p2`. It add node but not update node value. Now if I edit `p1` it add node and update value. Then I  again edit `p2` the value is updating. I think this is work because when updating `p1` fire a event responsible for update binding.

At last if in attached property method `TextBox_TextChanged` uncomment `textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();` everything works fine. It looks like something binding glitch.

The main question is: This is a bug or I something missing?

Bellow is all necessary code to reproduce issue.

To show `p1` and `p2` edit controls select node in TreeView.

```xml
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp13.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp13" mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:xlinq="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Linq;assembly=System.Xml.Linq"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" ObjectType="{x:Type xlinq:XElement}" MethodName="Parse">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <system:String xml:space="preserve">  
<![CDATA[  
<root>
    <header Name="Headre 1">
        <p0>text</p0>
    </header>
</root> 
]]>                  </system:String>

                <xlinq:LoadOptions>PreserveWhitespace</xlinq:LoadOptions>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TreeView x:Name="tv" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, Path=Elements}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="header">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribute[Name].Value}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, Path=Xml, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=tv, Path=SelectedItem}" Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="header">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--ROW P1-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="p1:" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Element[p1].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                local:TextChangedAction.AddNodeIfNotExists="p1" />
                        <!--ROW P2-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="p2:" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Element[p2].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                local:TextChangedAction.AddNodeIfNotExists="p2" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WpfApp13
{
    public static class TextChangedAction
    {

        #region AddNodeIfNotExists

        public static string GetAddNodeIfNotExists(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(AddNodeIfNotExistsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAddNodeIfNotExists(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(AddNodeIfNotExistsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddNodeIfNotExistsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AddNodeIfNotExists", typeof(string), typeof(TextChangedAction), new PropertyMetadata(null, AddNodeIfNotExistsPropertyChanged));

        private static void AddNodeIfNotExistsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is TextBox textBox)
            {
                textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
            }
        }
        private static void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            var parentNode = (XElement)textBox.DataContext;
            var nodeName = GetAddNodeIfNotExists(textBox);

            if (parentNode.Element(nodeName) == null)
            {
                parentNode.Add(new XElement(nodeName));
                //uncoment a line bellow and everything works fine
                //textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I think it's more of an edge case than a bug.
Indeed, you have on one hand a binding, from a TextBox to a XElement, and on the other an TextChanged event, fired from the same TextBox and creating the same XElement.

I don't think we can tell in which order that is supposed to happen, or if it can happen at all.

As an example, try to add `Mode=TwoWay` in your TextBoxes' bindings. You'll notice that the problem is still here if you add text to `p2`, but as soon as you add text to `p1`, `p2` starts working as intended.

I think the easiest solution is to forget binding in your specific case, and simply use a code-behind event.

Add this code in your MainWindow.xaml.cs (or whatever its name is):

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    XElement parentNode = tb.DataContext as XElement;

    string nodeName = tb.Tag as string;

    XElement node = parentNode.Element(nodeName);
    if (node == null)
    {
        node = new XElement(nodeName);
        parentNode.Add(node);
    }

    node.Value = tb.Text
}
```

And modify your textboxes as to set their `Tag` property to the corresponding XElement's name:

```
<!--ROW P1-->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="p1:" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Tag="p1" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
<!--ROW P2-->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="p2:" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Tag="p2" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: I have to add that this was an interesting subject to study; I tried using a converter, a multiconverter, but couldn't do something clean in the end. I think MVVM would be the best way to deal with it in a proper manner.

Comment: I bet you could write the whole thing as an attached behavior. But nanoquibbles aside, I've been kicking this around as well and came up equally empty on why OP's approach misbehaves as it does -- just the same intuition that it's order-related. An MVVM solution might be a fair bit of work, depending on how arbitrarily OP wants the UI to be able to modify the XML. But that's what I'd do.

Comment: I know how to make to this work. I don't know why it one time work and another time doesn't work. Should I report a bug to Microsoft?

Comment: @siwydym67 you can try if you really want to, but as I said, this is an  edge case. You can't tell the order in which the actions are supposed to take place in advance, so even if you can fix it now, who knows if it'll still work in a future version of .Net. I don't think it qualifies as an actual bug.